# SharePoint 2010: Enterprise Keywords not saving for certain users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, keyword

User has owner permissions.  The user enters the keyword in the Enterprise Keywords field, saves the item, opens the same item for editing and the keywords are not there.  I can save keywords to the same document.  I am also in the owners group.  We tried the same keywords.  it worked for me, but not for my user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the Managed Metadata Service permissions:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625176.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-enterprise-metadata-and-keyword-settings-for-a-list-or-library-HA101665479.aspx#_Toc266878518

Can the user add Enterprise Keywords at all (as in if the term exists in MMS vs. a new term)?

Your post looks like this one which was never resolved:

[Enterprise Keywords not saving in a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35920/enterprise-keywords-not-saving-in-a-list)

Comment: The user cannot add any keyword, new or existing.  The app pool account has full permissions to the managed metadata service.